# Given two even numbers, find the sum of the squares of all even numbers between them

Tags: c++, loops

My task is to create a program that will prompt the user for two even `ints`, `finput` and `sinput`. After that, it should output the sum of the squares of all even numbers from `finput` to `sinput`, inclusive.

Here is my code which attempts to accomplish this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int finput, sinput;
    int evens, d;

    cout << "Please enter an EVEN number for your first input.(Make sure your first input is less than your second): " << endl;
    cin >> finput;
    cout << "Please enter an EVEN number for your second input.(Make sure your first input is less than your second): " << endl;
    cin >> sinput;
    cout << "Results: " << endl << "---------------------------------------------------" << endl;


    if (finput % 2 == 0 && sinput % 2 == 0) {
        if (finput < sinput) {
            while (finput < sinput) {
                evens = pow(2, finput);
                finput += 2;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "These numbers are not even. try again.";
        cout << endl << "Please enter two EVEN numbers. Your first input should be less than your second input (ex. 3  9; 50  100): " << endl;
        while (finput % 2 != 0 && sinput % 2 != 0) {
            cin >> finput >> sinput;
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that I have to somehow *store* each increment of the loop so I can add it to the running total, but I have no idea how to do this. Can somebody tell me how to complete the task?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What makes you think there's anything wrong with this code? Do you have an error case? Are you sure about that `pow` statement? Also, you can do this in O(1) without a loop, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for-loop` to loop through all numbers from `finput` to `sinput`. Make sure to increment by `2` each time to get all the even numbers from `finput` to `sinput`.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = finput; i <= sinput; i += 2){
    sum += i*i;
}
```

There is also a `O(1)` way to get the sum of all even squares between `finput` and `sinput`. You can achieve this using the formula `1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2 = (n)(n+1)(2n+1)/6`:

```
int sum = 4*(sinput/2)*(sinput/2+1)*(sinput+1)/6
        - 4*(finput/2)*(finput/2+1)*(finput+1)/6 + finput*finput;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here:

```
evens = pow(2, finput);
```

First, you are not adding the square to the final result. Second, you are computing `2^finput` instead of `finput^2`. So that should be:

```
evens += pow(finput, 2);
```

or

```
evens += finput * finput;
```

Also, you need to initialize the accumulator to 0:

```
int evens = 0;
```